# How to generate PCIe atomic request from x86_64 CPU?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, atomic, pci-e

PCIe 3.0 supports atomic operation request(FetchAdd, Swap, CAS).
I try to generate PCIe atomic operation request from host by using Build-in function for memory model aware atomic operations, but so far it seems unsuccessful.
[image: __atomic_store_n and __atomic_exchange_n attempt]

My CPU is AMD Ryzen 5 7600X and according to AMD ROCm it support PCIe atomic[text](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/tree/23beff10b8916c5302ff0df6750c3585e01ea517#supported-cpus)

I want to send PCIe atomic request to my endpoint device (SSD) that connected by PCIe to PC x86-64, even if endpoint does not support atomic completer capability.

Here is my host CPU and endpoint device's atomic capability and request enable configuration:

Host CPU(AMD Ryzen 5 7600X):

```
  1. DecCap2: AtomicOpsCap: Routing+ 32bit+ 64bit+ 128bitCAS-
  2. DevCtl2: AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn+ (Default value is 0)
```

Endpoint:

```
  1. DecCap2: AtomicOpsCap: Routing- 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
  2. DevCtl2: AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
```

#### My questions:

1. Which assembly instruction can generate PCIe Atomic Request in x86_64 CPU?
2. When Endpoint does not support Atomic Completer, will Root Complex still choose to send AtomicOp request?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the document you linked that  says that AMD Ryzen supports PCIe atomics only means that it supports upstream atomics from a device to memory. I'm not aware of any x86 CPU that has a CPU instruction to generate atomics toward a device. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266325/8422330

Comment: For example, the Remote Atomics instructions (RAO), such as AADD, documented by Intel in the [future features document](https://cdrdv2-public.intel.com/782879/architecture-instruction-set-extensions-programming-reference.pdf) only work with WB memory, not with PCIe devices.

Comment: Where it says "DevCtl2: AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn+", that means that the root port can forward an atomic request received from a device to another device.